# NSUserDefaults vs Core Data

Tags: php, swift, core-data, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I am creating an app like Snapchat using `Swift` and `PHP` as my backend. I am using `MSQL` is my database. I am currently saving my user information in `NSUserDefaults` (it is only a couple variables like username, email, id etc). I heard if I am creating a full scale app for more than 100k users I am supposed to use Core Data so I am not sure if I should switch over. As i said it is only a small number of variables is stored, rest is in my database. Will i be noticing any speed differences?

Comment: Why would the number of users that have downloaded your application affect the viability of using NSUserDefaults vs. CoreData to save usernames? Seems illogical.

Comment: Don't lean on NSUserDefaults for persistence. NSUserDefaults should be used for storing simple user settings. Utilize Core Data, there's a brief learning curve but it's better suited for persisting records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *can't* logically follow that the number of users downloading your app has any impact on the viability of using CoreData vs. UserDefaults to save someone's **username** and **email**. However, it's plausible that there are advantages one way or the other (independent of scalability). Personally, I use UserDefaults to save that information, but can't imagine it makes much a difference.

However, the fact that you're keeping all *other* data (user profiles, photos, messages) exclusively in a remote database is quite worrisome. Without any kind of caching, your Snapchat app should probably be marketed toward the older generation, keen to reminisce in the days of Dial-Up with an app crafted to pull any data (other than username/email) repeatedly from a remote database. For this purpose, you *ought* to use CoreData or a similar alternative (SQLite, etc.). It's absolutely crucial that you have some sort of local database if you want to scale. And please, dear God, do not attempt to save this type of data to UserDefaults.

Unless, of course, you find my facetious proposition appealing.